# Parsing complex JSON Data using VBA JSON

Tags: json, vba, excel

Im trying to parse data from a Json File using VBA Json which is like this :

```
{
    "a131331": {
        "time" : "10:28 a.m.",
        "title" : "first"
    },
    "b319810" : {
        "time" : "11:14 a.m.",
        "title" : "third"
    },
    ...
}
```

I want to replace the key `a131331` with `1`, `b319810` with `2` and so on in the first column of a spreadsheet, and place the other corresponding data in the next columns. So my excel sheet would look like:

```
ID|Time |Title
1 |10.28|first
2 |11.14|third
```

Im using this code in VBA :

```
Public Sub ExcelJson()
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim JsonTS As TextStream
    Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile("M:\Ds Downloads New\test.json", ForReading)
    JsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
    JsonTS.Close
    Set JSON = ParseJson(JsonText)

    i = 2

    For Each Item In JSON

        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("time")
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item("title")
        i = i + 1

    Next

    MsgBox ("complete")

End Sub
```

I understand I can create a column with the number range starting from 1 for the ID column. But how do I parse those objects `a131331` and `b319810`?

Comment: 1. You'd need to show us your ParseJSon function. 2. Don't understand why you need to parse them if you don't need those key ids???

Comment: Just store `i` in your cell?  `Steets(1).Cells(i,1).Value = i - 1` for the `ID` column, `Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item("time")`, etc.

Comment: Try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42543860/2165759), `JSON.Parse` and `JSON.ToArray`, then you can process the array or output it to worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON object is a Scripting Dictionary, so you can either iterate over the Keys, or over the Values.

Iterating over the Keys:

```
Dim Json As Object, k

'getting the JSON content from a worksheet for testing purposes...
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Sheet1.Range("B1").Value)

For Each k In Json.Keys

    Debug.Print k, Json(k)("time"), Json(k)("title")

Next k
```

Output:

```
a131331       10:28 a.m.    first
b319810       11:14 a.m.    third
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much Tim !